# Get clipboard into Watch window when Debugging VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I'm running a macro on a word document.

After doing a `Selection.Copy` and running on, while debugging, I want to be able to see what was actually copied, and if it was mistakenly replaced.

Is there a way to "watch" Windows' clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way. At the beginning of my code:

```
Dim obj As New DataObject
obj.GetFromClipboard
```

I needed to reference Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library to have the "DataObject".
At first I couldn't find it on the list - had to browse for FM20.dll.

The second line could be typed on need in immediate window, instead of writing it in the code. I found it easier this way.

Then, in the watch window, I put `obj.GetText` as a watch expression and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

`clipbrd.exe` is the Windows clipboard viewer.

Comment: I'm on WIN7, can't find such a file.

Comment: It seems it is not in win 7 indeed. See this: http://www.winvistaclub.com/t72.html